# Intent to navigate Status screen

Tags: android, android-intent, android-8.0-oreo, android-settings

By using below intent i can navigate to "about phone" screen

```
Intent intentOpenBluetoothSettings = new Intent();
intentOpenBluetoothSettings.setAction(Settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS);                                                    
startActivity(intentOpenBluetoothSettings);
```

But I want to navigate to Status screen, like Settings -- > about phone -- > Status.

How to achieve this programatically using Intent?

I want to navigate here:

[image]

Comment: I don't know if there's an Intent action specifically for this. But you could find out the name of the activity yourself using something like `adb logcat ActivityManager:V *:S` while you navigate to this page, and then use that information in your app to launch the activity.

Comment: Thanks @Michael , By using **adb logcat ActivityManager:V *:S** this command I got activity name like **com.android.settings/.Settings$StatusActivity** .Then I created an Intent.

`Intent statusIntent = new Intent();
statusIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
statusIntent.setClassName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.Settings$StatusActivity");
startActivity(statusIntent);`